# Unexpected Response From API call using axios.get

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to fetch some data using axios.get

The following endpoint takes in a currency and a value and then SHOULD return a single number, by converting the given value into Bitcoin.

`https://blockhain.info/tobtc?currency=${selected}&value=${amount}

I get a 200 response in Postman and in my app, however the following code returns the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('https://blockhain.info/tobtc?ch=1&currency=ARD&js=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJKb2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTY3NjI5MDM2MiwiaWF0IjoxNjc2MjgzMTYyLCJpc3MiOiJKb2tlbiIsImpzIjoxLCJqdGkiOiIydDFsbDlzb3NmYXEzaGRva28zZ2xoMG8iLCJuYmYiOjE2NzYyODMxNjIsInRzIjoxNjc2MjgzMTYyMTgzMDA4fQ.caJ-5pxUVIzmLQ1nSsKaamzwxj-rJkNHeVxlBXuLun8&sid=f1cb455e-ab81-11ed-9cae-f009f3843e4f&value=123');</script>
  </body>
</html>
LOG  {"config": {"adapter": ["xhr", "http"], "data": undefined, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": [Object], "maxBodyLength":
-1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "https://blockhain.info/tobtc?currency=ARD&value=123", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": "
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('https://blockhain.info/tobtc?ch=1&currency=ARD&js=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJKb2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTY3NjI5MDM2MiwiaWF0IjoxNjc2MjgzMTYyLCJpc3MiOiJKb2tlbiIsImpzIjoxLCJqdGkiOiIydDFsbDlzb3NmYXEzaGRva28zZ2xoMG8iLCJuYmYiOjE2NzYyODMxNjIsInRzIjoxNjc2MjgzMTYyMTgzMDA4fQ.caJ-5pxUVIzmLQ1nSsKaamzwxj-rJkNHeVxlBXuLun8&sid=f1cb455e-ab81-11ed-9cae-f009f3843e4f&value=123');</script>
  </body>
</html>
", "headers": {"accept-ch": "Sec-CH-UA, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile", "cache-control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length": "504", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Mon, 13 Feb 2023 10:12:42 GMT", "server": "Cowboy"}, "request": {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": false, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {"accept-ch": "Sec-CH-UA, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile", "cache-control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length": "504", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Mon, 13 Feb 2023 10:12:42 GMT", "server": "Cowboy"}, "_method": "GET", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://blockhain.info/tobtc?currency=ARD&value=123", "_performanceLogger": {"_closed": false, "_extras": [Object], "_pointExtras": [Object], "_points": [Object], "_timespans": [Object]}, "_requestId": null, "_response": "
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('https://blockhain.info/tobtc?ch=1&currency=ARD&js=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJKb2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTY3NjI5MDM2MiwiaWF0IjoxNjc2MjgzMTYyLCJpc3MiOiJKb2tlbiIsImpzIjoxLCJqdGkiOiIydDFsbDlzb3NmYXEzaGRva28zZ2xoMG8iLCJuYmYiOjE2NzYyODMxNjIsInRzIjoxNjc2MjgzMTYyMTgzMDA4fQ.caJ-5pxUVIzmLQ1nSsKaamzwxj-rJkNHeVxlBXuLun8&sid=f1cb455e-ab81-11ed-9cae-f009f3843e4f&value=123');</script>
  </body>
</html>
", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "https://blockhain.info/tobtc?currency=ARD&value=123", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": {"accept-ch": "Sec-CH-UA, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile", "cache-control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "content-length": "504", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Mon, 13 Feb 2023 10:12:42 GMT", "server": "Cowboy"}, "responseURL": "https://blockhain.info/tobtc?currency=ARD&value=123", "status": 200, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined}
```

Why am I getting all this unecessary stuff on a simple GET request when all I need is the number?

Here is the image in postman:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on your request URL, it should be  `https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=${selected}&value=${amount}`
`C` is missing in the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks for that! Confused as to why Im getting a 200 OK response if the URL is wrong ?